# Why won't my setblock command which summons a chest put the items inside I told it too?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

So I am making a Minecraft command with /setblock. It is supposed to put a 32K diamond sword in the first slot, and a 32K diamond axe on the second slot. Here is my command (it's ver big):

```
setblock ~ ~1 ~ chest{Items:[{id:"diamond_sword",slot:0,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"bane_of_arthropods",lvl:32768},{id:"fire_aspect",lvl:32768},{id:"knockback",lvl:32768},{id:"mending",lvl:32768},{id:"sharpness",lvl:32768},{id:"smite",lvl:32768},{id:"sweeping_edge",lvl:32768},{id:"unbreaking",lvl:32768}]}},{id:"diamond_axe",slot:1,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"bane_of_arthropods",lvl:32768},{id:"efficiency",lvl:32768},{id:"mending",lvl:32768},{id:"sharpness",lvl:32768},{id:"silk_touch",lvl:32768},{id:"smite",lvl:32768},{id:"unbreaking",lvl:32768}]}}]} replace
```

This however, only puts the 32K axe in the first slot, not the 32K sword in the first, and the 32K axe in the second. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "b" after the slot number.  Try the following:

```
setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:chest{Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{lvl:32768,id:"bane_of_arthropods"},{lvl:32768,id:"fire_aspect"},{lvl:32768,id:"knockback"},{lvl:32768,id:"mending"},{lvl:32768,id:"sharpness"},{lvl:32768,id:"smite"},{lvl:32768,id:"sweeping_edge"},{lvl:32768,id:"unbreaking"}]}},{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:diamond_axe",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{lvl:32768,id:"bane_of_arthropods"},{lvl:32768,id:"efficiency"},{lvl:32768,id:"mending"},{lvl:32768,id:"sharpness"},{lvl:32768,id:"silk_touch"},{lvl:32768,id:"smite"},{lvl:32768,id:"unbreaking"}]}}]}
```

Also consider posting on [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) in the future.